# Can Express Migration Tool 2.0 migrate to Sitecore 8.2 Update-4

Tags: express-migration-tool

I am asking this question, because last time link to Express Migration Tool 2.0 ( https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Express_Migration_Tool/20/Express_Migration_Tool_20_Initial_Release.aspx ) is present on Sitecore 8.2 Update-1 ( https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/82/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_82_Update1.aspx ). All further updates does not show this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool is not compatible with version newer than Sitecore 8.2 Update 1.

You should install install upgrade package using the **UpdateInstallationWizard** to upgrade from 8.2.1 to to 8.2.4

Comment: I think you can update from 8.2-1 to 8.2-4 in 1 step.. no?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

Officially the tool do not support 8.2 Update-4. However I have succesfully migrated to from 6.5 and 6.6 to 8.2 update 4. This was done on simple solutions, with limited or no usages of other features but the Sitecore CMS.

If you use WFFM or anything else like this, I would recommend using the tool to 8.2 update 1, and upgrade manually to 8.2 update 4.